# tcl analog of ruby REST request

Tags: rest, web, tcl

I have the following ruby code (from Codeacademy API course).

```
require 'open-uri'

# Open http://placekitten.com/ for reading on line 4!
kittens = open('http://placekitten.com')
body = kittens.read[559, 441]

# Add your puts statement below!

puts body
```

How to write it in tcl?

Comment: What does `read[559,441]` do?

Comment: @glenn jackman: it read specific characters from the output which give ASCII cat image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to dump the document? If so, the following is the minimal code:

```
package require http
puts [http::data [http::geturl "http://placekitten.com"]]
```

Comment: I think he also wants to use `string range` on that output. Or, more likely, tDOM and an XPath term to extract that comment in a _sane_ way…

Comment: Ah, so he wants the kitten picture. Actually a simple `split` or `regexp` will do as well since html comments can't be nested.